# If $2xy^3dx+x^2y^2dy=ydx-xdy $ and $y(2)=1$, then the value of $y(-1) is $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $2xy^3dx+x^2y^2dy=ydx-xdy $ and $y(2)=1$, then find the value of $y(-1)$.

My approach
$\frac{x}{y}=t$, $\frac{ydx-xdy}{y^2}=dt$

$2xydx+x^2dy=\frac{ydx-xdy}{y^2} $

$2xydx+x^2dy=dt$

$x=ty;dx=ydt+tdy$

$2xydx+x^2dy=dt$.

Even if I try to substitute the above term it is getting complicated.

Comment: Divide by $y^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Divide the entire equation by $y^2$.

Then the equation becomes $d(x^2y) = d(\frac{x}{y})$.

Can you take it from here?